# Trying to send an Email through python with Gmail or Outlook

Tags: python, email

Hello I am fairly new to python and stumbled upon this cool feauture that with only a few lines of code, python can send emails.

I am currently not sure if the code that I have below works or if its something on my end? Since I am totally new to this I have no way to test if I am on the right track or not.

When running the code, it compiles with no problem but I never receive the messages.

Also, I am sending emails to myself, so I should see them rather quickly.

Here is my Outlook code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'myemail@hotmail.com'
mail.Subject = 'Hello this is you!
mail.Body = 'Hello!!!!!!'
mail.HTMLBody = '<h2>This is an H2 message</h2>' #this field is optional

# To attach a file to the email (optional):
attachment  = "C:/Users/OneDrive/Documents/Desktop/Social_Network_Ads.csv"
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

mail.Send()
```

Here is my Gmail Code:

```
import smtplib

fromaddr = 'myemail@gmail.com'
toaddrs  = 'myemail@gmail.com'
msg = 'There was a terrible error that occured and I wanted you to know!'


# Credentials (if needed)
username = '###username###'
password = '###password###'

# The actual mail send
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

Please let me know why I am not receiving the email or why its showing as not sent?

EDIT:

I am connected to my local hotmail account and I am logged into Gmail, so I am hopping its not a connection issue.

When I go to check my sent folder nothing seems to have been sent

Comment: Is outlook actually sending the email?

Comment: No I checked my sent folder and nothing was sent.

Comment: Would it have anything to do with Outlook or gmail application being open separately? I needed win32com recently for Excel (.xlsb) and had issues if Excel (or the files) were open / already existed. I made sure Excel was closed and used excel.Quit() to finish the script.

Comment: @Hatt No I have tried closing the applications when running the code and that didn't work either? I have been researching this issue for awhile now and I can't seem to find many other people with this same issue unless its a syntax error. I am not too sure how to fix this issue?

Comment: @Hatt I Have also tried many variations of the code above to try and debug the issue but have come to a dead end